# gsutil cp in dockerfile does not copy file

Tags: docker, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I am trying to deploy my FastAPI app on Cloud Run, and in the Dockerfile I'd like to copy a file on my GCS Bucket and read it in the API. It somehow does not copy the file.

This is the copy lines in my Dockerfile:

```
FROM google/cloud-sdk AS gcloud
RUN mkdir ./models
RUN gsutil cp gs://rim-models/model_1.pkl ./models/model_1.pkl
```

And when I created an image with `gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/project-id/api-name --timeout=3600`, it shows that the file was copied:

```
Copying gs://rim-models/model_1.pkl ...
- [1 files][399.8 KiB/399.8 KiB]
Operation completed over 1 objects/399.8 KiB.
```

However, I got this error in the API:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'models/model_1.pkl'
```

When I run the command `gsutil cp gs://rim-models/model_1.pkl ./models/model_1.pkl` locally, it does copy the file `model_1.pkl` to my local directory `models`. So why did it not work when I deployed the app to Cloud Run?

EDIT: After changing all `models` paths to either all relative or all absolute, the error remains.

Answer (score 2):

Your container creation contains mistakes or inconsistency in the directory definition.

```
RUN mkdir /models
RUN gsutil cp gs://rim-models/model_1.pkl ./models/model_1.pkl
```

First line, you create the absolute path `/models`, in the seconds, you use the relative path `./models`

You can either use the full path, or the relative, but there is lack of consistency.

In your API error, the mention is `models/model_1.pkl`, obviously a relative path. I don't know the full path where your API look the data, but you have to fix all this small unaligned directory definition

Comment: After changing all `models` path to either all relative or all absolute, I still have the same error